# Can't create war archive for spring-boot web project

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle

I have created spring-boot web project by Intellij and can't see my web archive anywhere after build or start project by SpringApplication.run() method. On the documentation page I found three clauses that should be observed

1. The first step in producing a deployable war file is to provide a SpringBootServletInitializer
2. Apply the war plugin to the project
3. Ensure that the embedded servlet container doesn’t interfere with the servlet container to which the war file will be deployed by adding
   `providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'`
   to build script

My servlet initializer

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {    
   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(RegTemplateApplication.class);
        }

    }
```

My build script

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: I'm able to create a WAR with IntelliJ 2016 and Maven.  I don't have the code in front of me now.  I'll try and find it.  I don't see the plugin that I think you need.  Can you highlight it in your Gradle setup?

Comment: I am no sure with graidle but with maven you can run mvn package and have a WAR file generated in the /target folder

Comment: running the application will of course not create a war. You have to use `gradle build` on the command line (or from within IntelliJ) to create the artifacts. Running the app is, just as the name states, running the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assemble war you should run `gradle assemble`

This command will create war artifact from `src/main/webapp` sources by default.
Also check out that your sources are in that dir or you should provide `webAppDirName` property

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to build using:

```
gradle clean build
```

and found the web archive in this directory:

```
./build/libs/build.war
```

Note: you have to install gradle on your machine.